# What is the pullback of this map?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let M be a manifold and let $m \in M $. We denote by $\mathcal{A}(M)$ and $\mathcal{A}(m)$ the space of differential form of M and and $ \lbrace m \rbrace  $ respectively.

If we Consider  the inclusion map  $i : \lbrace m \rbrace \rightarrow M $, then what is the explicit description of its  the pullback : $ i^* : \mathcal{A}(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}(m)$?

Comment: Are there any non-zero $k$-forms on a zero-dimensional manifold?

Comment: @Ted shifting, if $k >0$ there is no k-forms, but I'm not sure what can we say if k=0 ? My thought about this,  is if $\omega = \sum_k \omega_{[k]} \in \mathcal{A}(M)$, then $i^* \omega = \omega_{[0]}$ ?

Comment: Evaluated at $m$, of course.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, thank you sir !